# Find files matching pattern in the file array

Tags: perl

I have code in perl as below. Trying pick files which matches the pattern.

```
opendir ERR_STAGING_DIR, "$ERR_STAGING" or die "$PID: Cannot open directory $ERR_STAGING";
@allfiles = grep !/^$ERR_STAGING\/\./, map "$ERR_STAGING/$_", readdir(ERR_STAGING_DIR);
closedir(ERR_STAGING_DIR);

$ERR_FILETYPE = basename ($ERR_FILETYPE);

$ERR_FILETYPE =~ s/\./\\\./g;
$ERR_FILETYPE =~ s/\*/\*/g;

@file_type = grep /^$ERR_STAGING/./$ERR_FILETYPE$/, @allfiles;
$numelements = @file_type;
if ($numelements <= 0) {
    print LOG "$PID: No files match specified pattern, exiting.\n";
    &HandlerDie($NO_FILE_TYPE, $current_poid);
}
```

Here is what I'm doing above. Grep all files from ERR_STAGING directory. grep files matching pattern `'BVN*.fin.bc_lerr.xml.bc'` e.g `BVN_201608250000.fin.bc_lerr.xml.bc` and do something with the file. However the above code is returning files which doesn't match pattern too, it also pickup some temp directories.

Comment: Where the pattern `BVN*...` in your code ?

Comment: @Mike ERR_FILETYPE is a variable set in property files $ERR_FILETYPE = "BVN*.fin.bc_lerr.xml.bc";

Comment: Be aware that if your `$ERR_STAGING` variable happens to contain any of the regex metacharacters `\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .` you may get unexpected behavior. I would recommend that you always quote regular expressions where you want to match literal strings, see [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for more information.

Comment: Rather than hacking away trying to turn a shellglob into a regex - as you seem to be - can I suggest that what you really need is `glob` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct two rows:

```
$ERR_FILETYPE =~ s/\*/.\*/g;                      # Add DOT

@file_type = grep /\/$ERR_FILETYPE$/, @allfiles;  # such a filter is sufficient
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest an alternative - you mention `'BVN*.fin.bc_lerr.xml.bc'` as a pattern.

But that's not a regular expression (well, ok, it is - but I'm pretty sure you don't want 'zero or more `N`' you want 'anything after `BVN`). And you appear to be trying to convert it into a regex.

That means you're actually looking a shell glob, not a regex. They're similar, but not the same.

So can I suggest instead of `readdir` and `grep` that instead what you want is [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

Then you can:

```
my @files = glob ( '/path/to/BVN*.fin.bc_lerr.xml.bc' );
```

... and that's it. It'll expand your pattern using *shell* logic, not *regex* logic - and then read `/path/to` to find files matching that.

So in your example:

```
my @files = glob ( "$ERR_STAGING/$ERR_FILETYPE" );
```

Comment: This makes lot sense too.